# Condicional desde base de datos toma el dato, pero el else en el template no muestra el dato

Tags: javascript, django, leaflet

Si hay datos en la base de datos, el plano se muestra bien, toma bien los datos, pero si debe entrar en else, no muestra el plano por algún error.
En el ejemplo, los datos de la base de datos son los mismos que tenemos en el {% else %} pero al entrar en else no funciona.

¿Qué sucede?

```
{% for map in map %}
      var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [
          {% if map %}
            {{ map.longitude_conf_map }}
          {% else %}
            43.310789
          {% endif %}  
          ,
          
          {% if map %}
            {{ map.latitude_conf_map }}
          {% else %}
            -1.970963
          {% endif %}
          ],
          
        zoom:
          {% if map %}
            {{ map.zoom_conf_map }}
          {% else %}
            13.5
          {% endif %}
          ,
        layers: [grayscale,ebar1,ebap1,rdap1,esap1,drap1,ecs1,edar1,ddap1,plvm1,cc1,rep1,otros1]
      });

  {% endfor %}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El for debe ir dentro de cada if. Así funciona perfecto:

**Código:**

```
 var longitudExample=43.310789;
 var latitudeExample=-1.970963;
 var zoomExample=13.5;

     var map = L.map('map', {
            
            center: [
              {% if map %}
                {% for map in map %}
                  {{ map.longitude_conf_map }}
                {% endfor %}
              {% else %}
                longitudExample
              {% endif %},
              
              {% if map %}
                {% for map in map %}
                  {{ map.latitude_conf_map }}
                {% endfor %}
              {% else %}
                latitudeExample
              {% endif %}],
    
            zoom:
              {% if map %}
                {% for map in map %}
                  {{ map.zoom_conf_map }}
                {% endfor %}
              {% else %}
                zoomExample
              {% endif %},
    
            layers: [grayscale,ebar1,ebap1,rdap1,esap1,drap1,ecs1,edar1,ddap1,plvm1,cc1,rep1,otros1]
          });
```